# inserting values into database using java netbeans

Tags: java, mysql

It is a simple program for inserting into database.There are no errors but on inserting the value only 2 columns(year and subject) are getting affected in all the other 4 columns it is showing null value.how do I correct it.....................................................................................................

File name-index.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>INSERT</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Insert File Details</h1>
    <form action="loginprocess.jsp">
        <table border="1">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>File No :</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="File No" value="" size="50"    /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Name" value="" size="50" />  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Place of Origin :</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="origin" value="" size="50"   /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Year :</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="year" value="" size="50" />  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Subject :</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="subject" value="" size="50"   /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>ISBN :</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="ISBN" value="" size="50" /> </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="reset" value="Clear" name="Clear" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" />

    </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

File name LoginDao.java

```java
package bean;
import java.sql.*;


public  class LoginDao {
    public static boolean validate(LoginBean bean){
        boolean status=false;
        try{
            Connection conn=ConnectionProvider.getConn();
            String sql="insert into file(Fileno,name,place,year,subject,ISBN) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";            
            PreparedStatement pstmt =conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstmt.setInt(1, bean.getfileno()); 
            pstmt.setString(2,bean.getname());
            pstmt.setString(3, bean.getoriginPlace());
            pstmt.setInt(4, bean.getyear());
            pstmt.setString(5, bean.getsubject());
            pstmt.setInt(6, bean.getisbn());

            int rs=pstmt.executeUpdate();
            if(rs>0){status=true;}
        }catch(Exception e){}

        return status;
    }
}
```

File name LoginBean.java

```java
package bean;                                                                          

public class LoginBean {
    private String name,subject,originPlace;
    private int fileno,year,isbn;

    public int getfileno() {
        return fileno;
    }

    public void setfileno(int fileno) {
        this.fileno = fileno;
    }

    public String getname() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setname(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getoriginPlace() {
        return originPlace;
    }

    public void setoriginPlace(String originPlace) {
        this.originPlace = originPlace;
    }

    public int getyear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setyear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getsubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setsubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public int getisbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public void isbn(int isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

}
```

File name-loginprocess.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">   
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<%@page import="bean.LoginDao"%>
<jsp:useBean id="obj" class="bean.LoginBean"/>

<jsp:setProperty property="*" name="obj"/>

<%
 boolean status=LoginDao.validate(obj);
 if(status){
 out.println("success");
 session.setAttribute("session","TRUE");
 }
 else
 {
 out.print("failed");}

 %>
<jsp:include page="index.jsp"></jsp:include>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would assume that your bean is missing those 4 other properties.  Have you tried debugging to see what is wrong?

Comment: I think setter method is defined in wrong way example: setsubject like setSubject()..can you try like this once...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jsp benas tag then property name in class(bean class) and `<input >` name is jsp must be same.only two field have same name. so only two value are inserted.

```
In class       in jsp 
 File No        fileno
```

So put same name in class and bean.

Comment: I changed it and its working but for Fileno and ISBN it is inputing 0 as the value.

Comment: You need to add proper getter setter method as well, in your code for isbn  there is no Proper setter method, setter method should be setIsbn() , note that "I" is capital . Please select my answer as "Answer".Thanks

Comment: public int getFileno() {
 return Fileno;
}

public void setFileno(int Fileno) {
 this.Fileno = Fileno;
}

Comment: the above is the get and set method for Fileno only this coloumn is left which is inputing 0 value

Comment: Please only 1 column is left. I would be extremely gratefull

Comment: I can't figure out , but something must be wrong?   Have you changed fileNo in jsp ?? check again input  name in jsp and property name in java class are same

Comment: yeah it is the same name="Fileno" in jsp

Comment: "Fileno" ... no put it as fileno in jsp  and in java class both.

Comment: do i also have to change getFileno() to getfileno

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Java cannot match the names in your `<input>` elements in your JSP file to the correct setter methods in the bean.  For example, you had this element and setter:

```
<input type="text" name="Name" value="" size="50" />

public void setname(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

and the property was never set (due to using `setname()` instead of `setName()`), but this did work:

```
<input type="text" name="year" value="" size="50" />

public void setyear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
}
```

because Java could match `year` (lowercase) to the correct setter.

Try using the following code:

```
<tr>
    <td>File No :</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="FileNo" value="" size="50"    /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Name" value="" size="50" />  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Place of Origin :</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Origin" value="" size="50"   /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Year :</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Year" value="" size="50" />  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Subject :</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Subject" value="" size="50"   /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>ISBN :</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="ISBN" value="" size="50" /> </td>
</tr>
```

Use this bean definition:

```
public class LoginBean {
    private String name,subject,originPlace;
    private int fileno,year,isbn;

    public int getFileNo() {
        return fileno;
    }

    public void setFileFo(int fileno) {
        this.fileno = fileno;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getOrigin() {
        return originPlace;
    }

    public void setOrigin(String originPlace) {
        this.originPlace = originPlace;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public int getISBN() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public void setISBN(int isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }
}
```